# Why does Grails require that I use `def` instead of `void` in a controller?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-controller

Take the following controller:

```
package test

class TestController {
    static defaultAction = "test"

    def test() {
        render "test"
    }
}
```

Why is `test` defined with `def test() {` instead of something like `void test() {`? Isn't the `def` keyword only used for closures or functions in a script (i.e. not in a Groovy class)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Burt's answer is correct but the real problem I was having is that I misunderstood what `def` is. Rather than being like `var` in JavaScript, you can think of it like `Object` in Java.

I thought that using `def` was like doing (JavaScript)

```
var test = function() {
    alert("test");
}
```

while in reality it's just like (Java)

```
public Object test() {
    return someObject;
}
```

It's not a different kind of function/closure, it's like a return type—`def` can be applied to any object (Groovy has no data primitives, so any value is also an object, unlike in Java).

It helps my Java brain to think of

```
def bar = "foo";
```

as

```
Object bar = "foo";
```

Answer (score 16):

`render` is void so in this case the `test` action could be `void`, but in the case where you return a model map the action has to be non-void:

```
def create() {
   [personInstance: new Person(params)]
}
```

Since some actions can return a value and some don't, the general syntax has to return `def` to support all variants.